# Show that $E_\mu$ has no periodic points that are not fixed points

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals, chaos-theory

**Problem statement**: *Consider $E_\mu(x)=\mu e^x$, where $0<\mu<1/e$. Show that $E_\mu$ has no periodic points that are not fixed points.*

It is in my understanding that what we need to show is that $E^{\circ n}_\mu(\overline{x})=\overline{x}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, that is we need to show that the orbit of any fixed point contains only one element. In this case, since $E_\mu(x)=e^{x-\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon > 1$, we can find that $\overline{x}=\ln(\overline{x})+\varepsilon$. And now is what seems to be the "foggiest" part: to show that $E^{\circ n}_\mu(\overline{x})=\overline{x}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we need to express $E^{\circ n}_\mu(\overline{x})$ explicitly, or use induction in some tricky way.

I'd appreciate some hints and/or clarifications.

Comment: Can you use Sharkovsky's theorem?

Comment: Does the fact that it's an increasing function help?

Comment: @Artem: unfortunately, not.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: I'm not sure. How may it help?

Comment: @sequence I recommend that you write down the definition of "increasing function", i.e. $f$ is increasing if $x_1<x_2$ implies ...  Next, suppose that $x_1$ and $x_2$ form an orbit of period two. You should find that you are close to a contradiction yielding the result for period two orbits. Working with an orbit of greater length is just a bit more work.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: if $x_1 < x_2$ and the orbit is of period greater than or equal to $2$, then $x_1 < x_2 < x_1 < x_2 ...$, which is impossible. Hence the contradiction. Very useful, thanks.